# Hibernate createSQLQuery concat multiple querys in WHERE clause

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle12c

im trying to do a SELECT in multiple Columns To find out if a name with last names concatenate in a string, exists in a table with names and first name and last name separates in columns.

```
query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS NOMBRE_COMPLETO LIKE :COMPLETE_NAME").setParameter("COMPLETE_NAME","%"+ nameComplete +"%");
```

this is throwing a NullPointerException.

What is the way i can do what im tying to do.

Im using Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NPE most likely has nothing to do with the SQL, probably your `session` is null.

Either way, that's not how you create that query, if I understood correctly, you want to find if the first name + last name is LIKE your given parameter, and maybe also the name column, not entirely sure if that's what you mean.

In that case, the query must be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME LIKE :COMPLETE_NAME AND CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, " ", LAST_NAME) AS NOMBRE_COMPLETO LIKE :COMPLETE_NAME
```

You can see the CONCAT doc (for mysql at least) here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Basically we're just adding a space between the first name and the last name.

The above query will check if the column `name` is LIKE `complete_name` and if the concatenation between the `first_name` and `last_name` is LIKE `complete_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try what you say, so far you were right about the session been null, i will study your query and try it to see if it help. Sorry if my question was hard to understand what im trying to do is to look if a complete name exists in a table were name and lastnames are separates in columns.I will add in the post that im using oracle 12c i think i cant use concat for more than two strings but i can concat two strings and then concat a third one.

Comment: man thanks you very much, now my code is working and i learn something new thanks to you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)